# Usar indices en los WHERE de los UPDATE y DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, optimización, indices

¿ Que tan optimo es el crear un indice para los campos usados en los WHERE de las sentencias UPDATE y DELETE ? He investigado sobre el tema y en general encuentro opiniones divididas, en general se habla de la penalizacion para todas las sentencias que no sean SELECT al crear indices por el hecho de tener que actualizar/crear un indice para cada registro, eso lo comprendo, sin embargo las opiniones se dividen al habla del uso de dicho indice en la clausula WHERE tanto del DELETE como del UPDATE:

```
DELETE FROM mitabla
WHERE miCampoIndexado = 123;

UPDATE miTabla
SET column1 = value1
WHERE miCampoIndexado = 456;
```

Debido a que en este caso en particular la busqueda se realizaria por un campo indexado (Similar a la busqueda en el SELECT), el INSERT si se veria perjudicado de cualquier forma ya que no hace uso de dicha clausula.

Comment: ¿Por qué se va a ver perjudicado el `INSERT`?

Comment: Corrígeme si me equivoco por favor, según comprendo cuando se realiza el INSERT, fuera del registro que se esta insertando con sus respectivos datos se debe crear un nuevo indice para dicho registro, teniendo de esta forma una carga extra.

Comment: Cuando se realiza un `INSERT` se crearán los índices que estén definidos para la(s) columna(s) de esa tabla. La cuestión es que un índice en realidad **no es una carga extra**, un índice se crea para optimizar resultados, por lo tanto no debes verlo como una *carga*, es todo lo contrario (si su existencia es justificada claro está). Y  claro que tiene su precio tener índices, pero el precio que pagas por tenerlos es algo así como una *inversión* que, repito, si creas los índices correctos, te va a reportar más ganancias que pérdidas.

Comment: La cuestión es muy simple: ¿Necesitas el índice realmente? entonces crea el índice sin miramientos. ¿No necesitas el índice?, no crees un índice innecesariamente porque entonces sí va a ser una carga. Y, ¿cómo sé si necesito un índice? Pues eso dependerá de muchas cosas, no hay una respuesta única porque cada aplicación, cada contexto, cada uso ... son diferentes. Y lo que va a definir su necesidad no es la preocupación de cómo funcione un `DELETE` o un `UPDATE`. Eso puede ser importante o no. Puede haber muchas otras circunstancias que sean decisivas para determinar o no su necesidad.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque crees un indice con los campos que usas en los WHERE, no sabes si el RDBMS los usara.
Más alla de la definicion de los indices, su uso o no, depende de la estadistica que el motor sql realiza sobre la consulta que estas realizando. Evalua el costo total y en funcion de eso decide si usar indices o no.
Adicionalmente, que HOY el motor de base de datos USE el indice que has creado, no significa que mañana, dentro de un mes o dentro de 6 meses continue usandolo.
La decision pasa por el monitoreo de la BD, y el analisis de las estadisticas para las consultas que realizas.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta. Teoricamente, en mi caso en particular debería usar el indice, ya que estaria filtrando un campo cuyos registros que se repiten es muy bajo, siendo asi no debería realizar un full scan, pero simulemos que forzo al RDBMS a usar dicho indice, aun asi mi duda inicial persiste.